# Android OS Keyboard moves Website Contents Up?

Tags: android, html, css

I have a mobile website with 4 elements that are absolutely positioned inside a 100% height div and when I click on the url bar the height on the div shrinks and pushes everything up.

Is there anyway to fix this issue? Or prevent it from changing the 100%? Or do I need to get the screen size using JS and fix it that way? As it works fine if I set it to an exact amount.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The android browser resizes the window when the keyboard is opened, there is no solution to prevent that.

Comment: So that stands to reason that the only way to prevent this issue is to manually assign the height property. Okay

Comment: Alternatively, couldn't you grab the viewport height *upon page load*, set it as a constant, then only refer to that constant?

Answer (score 5):

I was able to solve this by setting the z-index to -1 for the DOM element that gets in the way when the Android browser pops up the keyboard on the screen, as follows:

```
function hideNavbar() // needed for Android browser pushing up keyboard
{ 
    if (screen.height <= 480) // mobile
    {
        document.getElementById('navbar').style.zIndex = "-1";
    }
}
```

(I did this for an onclick event in the input text box), then, using an 'onblur' (i.e. when the user clicks out of the text/search box at the top of the screen), return the zindex of the navbar to '1':

```
function showNavbar() // needed for Android browser pushing up keyboard
{
    if (screen.height <= 480) // mobile
    {
        document.getElementById('navbar').style.zIndex = "1";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Similar to Charlie Carver, except using max-height and display:none

Tested on Galaxy S7 and iPhone 6s

```
.hide-element-on-keyboard {
    display:normal;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 550px) {
    .hide-element-on-keyboard {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer of Kevin Pajak worked for me. 
you can also use media queries:

your.css file:

```
.hide-element-on-keyboard {
    z-index: 1;
}

@media screen and (min-height: 300px) {
    .hide-element-on-keyboard {
        z-index: -1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a webview inside a LinearLayout and tried all solutions but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46868879/4403947) example worked. Added this snippet under the my activity of interest in the AndroidManifest.xml file.

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateAlwaysHidden"
```