# Android keyboard push up all the content

Tags: android, android-layout, xml-layout

I have a layout that looks like this .

[image]

When i click on the editText the screen keyboard push up all the content.
I want the header (orange area) to stay fixed and shown in the top of the screen.

The layout Code XML Code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
tools:context="com.projects.zak_dev.chatobe.MainActivity">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="592dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/tableRow"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.487"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/msg_bg" />

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:background="@color/mainGreenColor"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:foreground="@drawable/rounded_image"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/contact_img" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:text="Zakaria Guenna"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="Online"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</TableRow>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="381dp"
    android:layout_height="419dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/linearLayout"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tableRow"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="-311dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView8"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/contact_img" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView7"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/contact_img" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText5"
        android:layout_width="290dp"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_border"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Text View"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.19"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:layout_width="43dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_send"
        />
</LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is my XML Layout. 


I tried many answers like `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` but it is not working .
Can someone help me please !

Comment: Use `NestedScrollView` instead of `ScrollView`

Comment: What is the root view of the activity?

Comment: `CnstraintLayout` @SamuelRobert

Comment: Can you post the layout?

Comment: @SamuelRobert i added the xml layout code

Comment: Did you try changing `ScrollView` to `NestedScrollView`

Comment: @SamuelRobert yes , No change.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
```

to your `AndroidManifest.xml`